# Replace html tag with attributes by other tag in C#

Tags: c#, replace, tags, html

Basically, I want to replace html tag with other tag, for exemple:

```
</br> --> <LineBreak/>
<p> --> <Paragraph>
```

At start, I used

```
convertedHtml = html.replace("</br>","<LineBreak/>");
```

The problem with this method is it requiere to manage all case and I want a generic class. For exemple this method is not possible with this tags content:

```
<p class="foo"> --> <Paragraph>
<p id="bar"> --> <Paragraph>
.....
```

How can I resolve this ?

edit: Note That I do not know in advance which attributes are in the tags. I want replace tag who contains "p","/p", "br", "b", ...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use HTML Agility Pack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

You can get it via NuGet and it allows you to do get a list of nodes from a htmlDoc using xPath... You can then loop through these lists and do stuff to each node...

Comment: +1 Similar questions have been asked many times on this site, and that is the preferred way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expression to resolve this problem. More information is available at [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html). It will give you options for case sensitive/insensitive match.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in one of my older projects, where I did something similiar.

Take a look at this method I've been using:

```
    private static Regex _validAttributeOrTagNameRegEx = 
                       new Regex(@"^\w+$", RegexOptions.Compiled |RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        private const string STR_RemoveHtmlAttributeRegex = 
                           @"(?<=<)([^/>]+)(\s{0}=['""][^'""]+?['""])([^/>]*)(?=/?>|\s)";
    public static string RemoveHtmlAttribute(this string input, string attributeName) {
       if (_validAttributeOrTagNameRegEx.IsMatch(attributeName)) {
          Regex reg = new Regex(string.Format(STR_RemoveHtmlAttributeRegex, attributeName),
             RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
          return reg.Replace(input, item => item.Groups[1].Value + item.Groups[3].Value);
       } else {
          throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid HTML attribute name", "attributeName");
       }
    }
```

I'm not sure if that fits your requirements but it could be an idea on how to resolve it. After you removed the attributes from your html-tags you could use your old method `convertedHtml = html.replace("</br>","<LineBreak/>");`

Answer (score 0):

You could try some simple string operations, no additional namaspaces and tools included :

See this example, maybe it solves your problem:

```
string html = string.Concat("<p class=\"foo\">", 
                             "<p class=\"bar\">",
                             "<p>",
                             "</br>",
                             "<P>",
                             "</BR>"); // tags can be upper case as well

string strAux = html;
int tagOpenedAt=-1, tagClosedAt=-1;
bool isError = false;

do
{
   tagOpenedAt = strAux.IndexOf('<');
   tagClosedAt = strAux.IndexOf('>');
   if(tagOpenedAt<tagClosedAt)
   {
       string fullTag = strAux.Substring(tagOpenedAt, tagClosedAt - tagOpenedAt + 1);

       //<p> --> <Paragraph>
       if (fullTag.ToLower().Equals("<p>") || fullTag.ToLower().StartsWith("<p ")) 
           html = html.Replace(fullTag, "<Paragraph>");

       //</br> --> <LineBreak/>
       if (fullTag.ToLower().Equals("</br>")) 
           html = html.Replace(fullTag, "<LineBreak/>");

       //more if conditions as you need them

       strAux = strAux.Substring(tagClosedAt + 1);
   }
   else
   {
       isError = true;
   }
} 
while (tagOpenedAt>-1 && tagClosedAt>-1 && !isError);
```

Sorry for bad code, maybe you can improve by simply doing **.ToLower()** once instead of in every **if** statement. Also, I did not check for bad tags, the code just assumes html is valid.

**JUST EDITED A BIT**

```
       string html = string.Concat("<p class=\"foo\">","\n",
                                    "<p class=\"bar\">", "\n",
                                    "<p>", "\n",
                                    "</br>", "\n",
                                    "<P>", "\n",
                                    "</BR>");

        Console.WriteLine("HTML is :\n{0}\n", html);

        string strAux = html;
        int tagOpenedAt=-1, tagClosedAt=-1;
        bool isError = false;

        do
        {
            tagOpenedAt = strAux.IndexOf('<');
            tagClosedAt = strAux.IndexOf('>');
            if(tagOpenedAt < tagClosedAt)
            {
                string _fullTag = strAux.Substring(tagOpenedAt, tagClosedAt - tagOpenedAt + 1);
                string _lower = _fullTag.ToLower();
                string _replace = null;

                //<p> --> <Paragraph>
                if (_lower.Equals("<p>") || _lower.StartsWith("<p "))
                    _replace = "<Paragraph>";

                //</br> --> <LineBreak/>
                if (_lower.Equals("</br>")) 
                    _replace = "<LineBreak/>";

                //more if conditions as you need them

                if(_replace != null)
                {
                    html = html.Replace(_fullTag, _replace);
                    Console.WriteLine("Replaced {0} with {1}", _fullTag, _replace);
                }

                strAux = strAux.Substring(tagClosedAt + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                isError = true;
            }
        } 
        while (tagOpenedAt>-1 && tagClosedAt>-1 && !isError);

    Console.WriteLine("\nNew html is :\n{0}",html);
```